# React-bootstrap carousel don't start inside react-visibility-sensor when change interval value dynamically

Tags: carousel, visibility, viewport, intervals, autoplay

I'm using `React-Bootstrap Carousel` component inside `react-visibility-sensor` component, like this:

```
<VisibilitySensor>
    {
        ({ isVisible }) => (
            <Carousel
                activeIndex={activeIndex}
                controls={false}
                interval={isVisible ? 3000 : null}
                onSelect={this.handleChangeActiveIndex}
                fade={fade}
            >
                {
                    images
                }
            </Carousel>
        )
    }
</VisibilitySensor>
```

When `VisibilitySensor` component's changed, `isVisible` will be changed and interval value will be changed to null (for stop carousel) or 3000.
But, currently, when VisibilitySensor component's changed, `isVisible` was changed, component was re-render but Carousel not start slide (on `isVisible` is true).
Is it a my some mistake?
Thanks.